# wordpress array values containing variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

im trying to get data from specific category

```
 $kategori1= get_option('woo_kategori');
```

which the value is "clothes"

and i wanna put in array

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'product_cat' => $kategori11, 'orderby' => 'date' );
```

which is empty output.

```
'product_cat' => $kategori11,
```

im new here, and how to fill the product_cat value to my variable?

Comment: Well, you're using two different variables...`$kategori1 !== $kategori11`

Comment: my bad. i mean $kategori11= get_option('woo_kategori');

Comment: Try to inspect the `$kategori1` variable right after the call to `get_option()` - is it empty there? If so, it was never set.

Answer (score -2):

get_option is not going to work here. get_option only retrieves the values for a defined set of valid WordPress options. The list valid WordPress options can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference. If you could explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail, I may be able to help.

Comment: This is untrue. A user/plugin can define their own options: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you so much for clarifying!